# Look for a pattern of number in different column of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need help for the following task: how can I write a MATLAB code that compares, two by two, the odd and the even columns of a matrix, looking for two different patterns of numbers, respectively one for the even and one for the odd. 
I want the code to report in which column (for each pair) the pattern appears first.

For example: I have the following matrix

```
A = [0 1 0 1 0 0
     1 0 1 0 1 1
     0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 1 0 1 0 1
     0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

I want to look for two patterns, say: `100` (in the odd column of each pair of columns) and `010` (in the even columns of each pair of columns). Then, I want to report for each of the three pairs of columns if it appears first `100` in the odd or `010` in the even.

In the example we have:

odd(for columns 1,2 -> 100 appear first),

odd(for columns 3,4 -> 100 appear first),

even(for columns 5,6 -> 010 appear first)

Comment: Please elaborate the question or provide an example as to what "pattern" you are looking for.

Comment: ok I'm going to update the question

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Comment: Hope the example is clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's define the matrix `[mxn]` and two patterns:

```
A = randi([0 1],50,100);
[m,n]=size(A);
pat=[0 1 0 0 1];
pat2=[1 0 0 1 0];
```

Now, find the indices where the matrix contain these patterns. We will omit indices in the last lines because it's a pattern that continue in different columns, and we will omit the odd\even columns, for first\second pattern, respectively:

```
B=strfind(A(:).',pat);
B(mod(B,m)==0 | mod(B,m)>(m-length(pat)+1) | mod(B,2*m)<=m)=[];
C=strfind(A(:).',pat2);
C(mod(C,m)==0 | mod(C,m)>(m-length(pat2)+1) | mod(C,2*m)>m)=[];
```

Now, for the case that there is more than one match in the same column (as in the last column in our case), we will remain only the first of each:

```
[un,ind]=unique(ceil(B/m));
B2=ones(1,ceil(n/2))*numel(A);
B2(ismember(2:2:n,un))=B(ind);
[un,ind]=unique(ceil(C/m));
C2=ones(1,ceil(n/2))*numel(A);
C2(ismember(1:2:n,un))=C(ind);
```

And, the result:

```
result=double((B2-m)>C2);
result(intersect(find(~B2),find(~C2)))=-1;
```

The `result` will be a vector of `1 x (n/2)`, as the number of pairs of columns. while `1` represents the "win" of the odd column of each pair and `0` represents the "win" of the even column of each pair.

I generalized the code for the case that there is no pattern find in one of the columns. In this case, the second column of the pair is wins. In the case that both of the columns in the pair is lack its pattern, the result will be `-1`.

Comment: Thank you! just another question: if I want to modify this for a matrix 50x100 how can i change the values?

Comment: Do you know for sure that the first pattern will be present in all odd columns, and the second one will be present in all even columns?

Comment: See my edit, I adjusted it it to the general case anyway